# Is there any way to run impala shell with sql script with parameters？

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, impala

Is there any way to run impala shell with SQL script with parameters?

For example:

```
impala-shell -f /home/john/sql/load.sql /dir1/dir2/dir3/data_file
```

I got errors:

> Error, could not parse arguments "-f /home/john/sql/load.sql /dir1/dir2/dir3/data_file”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can specify a file of sql statements with `-f`, but it does not take a file of parameters. See the impala-shell documentation for more details:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/impala_impala_shell.html

Comment: This answer is true for version of Impala under the 2.5, today it's possible thanks to the @Raja answer

Answer (score 4):

This feature is available in CDH 5.7 / Impala 2.5 and higher.

The --var option lets you pass substitution variables to the statements that are executed by that impala-shell session, for example the statements in a script file processed by the -f option. You encode the substitution variable on the command line using the notation --var=variable_name=value. Within a SQL statement, you substitute the value by using the notation ${var:variable_name}.

See more details directly in the documentation : https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_set.html