# about how to run impala-shell within a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, impala

i have a problem when trying to execute this bash code:

```
function createImpalaPartition() {

period_id=$1;
database=$2
node=$3

actual_full=$(date -d@"$period_id" +%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/)
template="use c2d;create EXTERNAL TABLE exptopology_$period_id (child_id bigint,parent_id bigint,level INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format'=',', 'field.delim'=',') STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/hfc/sip/service/topology/$actual_full'"

echo "template is $template";
#impala-shell -V -i $node -d $database -q $template
impala-shell -V -i $node -q $template
}
```

This is how i invoke it:

```
createImpalaPartition $actual $impalaDatabase $impalaNode
```

where

```
actual=$(date +'%s')
impalaDatabase="dbName"
impalaNode="name_of_the_node"
```

the execution of the script returns:

```
[core@dub-vcd-vms170 ~]$ createImpalaPartition $actual $impalaDatabase $impalaNode
template is use c2d;create EXTERNAL TABLE exptopology_1428326587 (child_id bigint,parent_id bigint,level INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format'=',', 'field.delim'=',') STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/hfc/sip/service/topology/2015/04/06/14/23/'
Error, could not parse arguments "c2d;create EXTERNAL TABLE exptopology_1428326587 (child_id bigint,parent_id bigint,level INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format'=',', 'field.delim'=',') STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/hfc/sip/service/topology/2015/04/06/14/23/'"
 Usage: impala_shell.py [options]
```

As you can see, i have to create tables using a shell script.

UPDATE:

following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419361/is-there-any-way-to-run-impala-shell-with-sql-script-with-parameters), i can see that impala-shell can be used that way, but i am not using the correct params.

I have used -f instead of -q, the same error remains. Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the expansion of `$template` for the entire string to be treated as a single argument to `impala-shell`:

```
impala-shell -V -i $node "$template"
```

where `-V` enables verbose output. For non-verbose (quiet) output replace `-V` with `-q`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i discover how to resolve my problem.

```
function createImpalaPartition() {

period_id=$1;
database=$2
node=$3

actual_full=$(date -d@"$period_id" +%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/)
#UC=$(impala-shell -r -q "select count(1) from table where condition=1" -d $DB -i $HOST -B)
# attention, i have to use this way impala-shell
impala-shell -V -i $node -d $database -q "create EXTERNAL TABLE exptopology_$period_id (child_id bigint,parent_id bigint,level INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format'=',', 'field.delim'=',') STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/hfc/sip/service/topology/$actual_full'"
}
```

I can't use a template var with the create command, I have to pass the command this way.

Comment: With `-q` you cannot pass a USE statement and another query, fully qualify the names for any tables outside the default database. (Or use the -f option to pass a file with a USE statement followed by other queries.) [Refer](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_shell_options.html)