# Passing parameters to Impala shell

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I am running a impala query in while loop and for that I have created one separate query file and I am calling it from my shell script.

My question is: Can we pass shell variable matching with impala query in query file?

```
A="INSERT_SBP_ME_VS_ME_INCOME_LAST_THIRTY_DAYS_Q"${Count}

echo "value of A is $A"

source ${SBP2_MNY_IN_LAST_THIRTY_DAYS_QF}

${IMPALA_CON}  -q "${${A}}"
```

'A' value is like `INSERT_SBP_ME_VS_ME_INCOME_LAST_THIRTY_DAYS_Q1` (as count is 1)

I am doing this in this way but getting `bad substitution error` and I also tried

```
${IMPALA_CON}  -q "${A}"
```

but not getting a successful result.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for --var (IMPALA-2179). To substitute from the command line, you can do:

impala-shell -f test.q --var=L=2;

where test.q is:
select * from p_test limit ${VAR:L};

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be :

```
impala-shell -q "$A"
```

Refer:

[impala-shell Configuration Options](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_shell_options.html)

[similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472695/about-how-to-run-impala-shell-within-a-shell-script)

Comment: We have tried this but its is not working possibly because $A is unix variable and impala is expecting query variable ${Query_variable_Q1} which is present in the query file. any other solutuion?

Answer (score 0):

```
impala-shell -i node.domain:port -B --var"table=metadata" --var="db=retail" -f "file.sql"
```

file.sql:

> SELECT * FROM ${var:db}.${var:table}"